# Flutter: Submit TextFormField on Enter

Tags: flutter, listener, event-listener, keylistener, flutter-desktop

I'm working on a desktop application for Windows with Flutter. I want to listen to keyboard keys. I made a Login page and it has two TextFormFields, (one for Username and the other for Password).
When I press the 'enter' key on the keyboard, I want the form to be submitted as I pressed on 'Login' button. So if I pressed the 'enter' key from either Username or Password text fields, I want the app to act exactly as if I pressed the 'Login' Button.

Here is a picture of the Login Page:
--> [Login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LixWe.png)

Here is the code of Login Page:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../api/services/login_services.dart';
import '../../api/models/login_models.dart';
import '../../constants/constant_methods.dart';
import '../main_page/main_screen.dart';
import '../../constants/constant_variables.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
TextEditingController usernameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();
late LoginRequestModel loginRequestModel;
bool isUsernameEmpty = false;
bool isPasswordEmpty = false;
bool secure = true;
bool notSecure = false;
bool isLoading = false;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  loginRequestModel = LoginRequestModel(
    usernameController.text,
    passwordController.text,
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          gradient: loginPageGradient,
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Image.asset(
                  'assets/images/cloud_soft_logo.png',
                  height: 90,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 15),
                Text(
                  'Hoomy\'s Real Estate',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                Container(
                  width: 310,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: borderRadius(10.0),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(height: 20),
                      Text(
                        'Welcome',
                        style: Theme.of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .headline6!
                            .copyWith(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                foreground: Paint()..shader = linearGradient),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Please Log in to Your Account',
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      loginTextField("Username", "Username can't be empty",
                          usernameController),
                      loginTextField("Password", "Password can't be empty",
                          passwordController),
                      forgetPasswordButton(),
                      loginButton(context),
                      const SizedBox(height: 40),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget loginTextField(
  String labelText,
  String errorText,
  TextEditingController controller,
) {
  return SizedBox(
    width: 250,
    child: TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: labelText,
        errorText: labelText == "Username"
            ? isUsernameEmpty
                ? errorText
                : null
            : isPasswordEmpty
                ? errorText
                : null,
        suffixIcon: labelText == "Username"
             ? IconButton(
                onPressed: () {}, icon: const Icon(Icons.person, size: 20))
            : IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    secure = !secure;
                  });
                },
                icon: Icon(
                  secure ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
                  size: 20,
                ),
              )),
      obscureText: labelText == "Username" ? notSecure : secure,
      controller: controller,
    ),
  );
 }

 Padding forgetPasswordButton() {
   return Padding(
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20).copyWith(right: 30),
     child: Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
       children: [
         Theme(
           data: ThemeData(splashColor: Colors.transparent),
           child: TextButton(
             child: const Text('Forget Password'),
             onPressed: () {},
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
   );
 }

 DecoratedBox loginButton(BuildContext context) {
   return DecoratedBox(
     decoration: BoxDecoration(
       borderRadius: borderRadius(50.0),
       gradient: loginButtonGradient,
     ),
     child: ElevatedButton(
       style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
         primary: Colors.transparent,
         fixedSize: const Size(250, 50),
         shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
           borderRadius: borderRadius(50.0),
       )),
       child: isLoading
         ? CircularProgressIndicator(
             color: Colors.blue[800],
             backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
           )
         : const Text('Login'),
       onPressed: () {
         setState(() {
           usernameController.text.isEmpty
              ? isUsernameEmpty = true
              : isUsernameEmpty = false;
           passwordController.text.isEmpty
              ? isPasswordEmpty = true
              : isPasswordEmpty = false;
         });
         setState(() {
           isLoading = true;
         });
         LoginService.login(usernameController.text, passwordController.text)
             .then((response) {
           setState(() {
             isLoading = false;
           });
           if (response) {
             Navigator.of(context).push(
               MaterialPageRoute(
                 builder: (context) => const MainScreen(),
               ),
             );
           } else if (!response &&
               usernameController.text.isNotEmpty &&
               passwordController.text.isNotEmpty) {
             showErrorDialog(context, "Invalid Username or Password!");
            }
         });
       }),
   );
 }

 Future<dynamic> showErrorDialog(BuildContext context, String dialogContent) {
   return showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: SizedBox(
            width: 350,
            child: AlertDialog(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: borderRadius(10.0)),
              title: Text("Error",
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .bodyText1!
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.red)),
              content: Text(dialogContent,
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .headline2!
                    .copyWith(color: Colors.black87)),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  child: Text("OK",
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .bodyText1!
                        .copyWith(color: Colors.blue)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problems have you run into? What have you looked for and not found in a Google search?

Comment: I tried to use RawKeyboardListener but for some reason, text fields were not listening except for the 'enter' key, and I were not able to write anything in username and password fields

Comment: I face a similar issue where the 'Enter' key of the keyboard is not detected even though i have functions for onSubmitted and RawKeyBoardListener. However this issue happens only on some mobile browsers like OnePlus. Do you face this everywhere or only on some browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the field `onFieldSubmitted` and a `FormKey`:

```dart
// Widget attribute

final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();


// Widget method: build()

Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child:
  TextFormField(
    onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
     
      print('ENTER pressed'); 

      // Will trigger validation for ALL fields in Form.
      // All your TextFormFields (email, password) share
      // the SAME Form and thus the SAME _formKey.

      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) { 

        print('ALL FIELDS ARE VALID, GO ON ...');

      }
    }
  )
)
```

**Docs**

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html